# XSLT add values across multiple elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm stuck with a simple problem in my XML/XSLT

I can't really put a proper name on the problem, and therefore can't seem to find any solution.

XML:

```
<root>
   <entry gid ="001">
      <level_1>
         <target_value>50</target_value>
      </level_1>
   </entry>

   <entry gid ="001">
      <level_1>
         <target_value>30</target_value>
      </level_1>
   </entry>

   <entry gid ="002">
      <level_1>
         <target_value>40</target_value>
      </level_1>
   </entry>

   <entry gid ="002">
      <level_1>
         <target_value>20</target_value>
      </level_1>
   </entry>
</root>
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:for-each select="entry[@gid='001']">
   <xsl:if test="level_1/target_value != ''">
      <xsl:value-of select="sum(level_1/target_value)" />
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Result:
5030

Any help would be greatly appriciated!

Comment: It would help a lot if you said what output you wanted and how to derive that from your XML. I assume you want to sum all `/root/entry[@gid='001']/level_1/target_value` elements, resulting in a value of `80`?

Comment: Yes Borodin, that is exactly what I am after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have seen, your transform totals the only `level_1/target_value` element and outputs that for each `entry[@gid='001']` element.

Since you want a total across *all* `<entry>` elements with a `gid` of `001` you must write that in the nodeset you submit to `sum()`.

The XSLT looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(entry[@gid='001']/level_1/target_value)" />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output**

```
80
```